# Passing array from an override

Tags: java

I know I should understand how to do this but for the life of me I cant seem to how to pass the int[] array1 and set it equal to int[] toSort down below.  When trying to pass, I keep getting errors variable not found. Thank you for the support and help.

```
public class LoadListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Let the user pick the file
            JFileChooser pickFile = new JFileChooser();
            String fileName = "boo";
            Scanner input;
            if(pickFile.showOpenDialog(mPanel) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                fileName = pickFile.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                System.out.println(fileName);
                try {
                    input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
                    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer("");
                    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
                        String t = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Line to add: " + t);
                        data.append(t);

                    }

                    input.close();  
                    unsortedList.setText(data.toString());

                    String[] ss = ((unsortedList.getText()).replaceAll(" ",     ",")).split(fileName);                   

                    int[] array1 = new int[ss.length];
                    for (int i=0; i < ss.length; i++) {
                         array1[i] = Integer.parseInt(ss[i]);
                    }




                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mPanel, "Error opening" +
                            " and/or processing file: " + fileName,
                            "File Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            StringBuffer dataSorted = new StringBuffer("");

            // TODO: Get the list from the TextArea
            int[] toSort = array1;
```

Comment: You should read about *Java variables scope*.

Answer (score 1):

`array1` having scope only in the `actionPerformed()`  method of `LoadListener` class, and you are accessing it from another method of another class `ButtonListener`. This illegal in java

You can't access, one method local variable from another method. For more details, read oracle [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Answer (score 0):

@user3354341: Try the below code, it will solve your issue and also you need to learn about the scopes of the variables in java as you are trying to access the local variable of one class into another class.

```
public class LoadListener implements ActionListener {

        private int[] array1;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ...
            String[] ss = ((unsortedList.getText()).replaceAll(" ",     ",")).split(fileName);
            array1 = new int[ss.length];
            ...
        }
        public int[] getArrayData(){
        return array1;
        }
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            StringBuffer dataSorted = new StringBuffer("");

            LoadListener loadListener = new LoadListener();

            // TODO: Get the list from the TextArea
            int[] toSort = loadListener.getArrayData();
        }
}
```